# Deserializing Import Io JSON with multiple objects

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, json-deserialization

Morning all,

Im using Newtonsoft.JSON to deserialize a JSON response from Import Io. I have successfully used http://json2csharp.com/ to build a data model successfully in one instance to gain access to the data, however in that instance only one JSON object was returned. I am now working on a new piece of JSON that is being returned with multiple objects and i'm hitting issues with the following error message:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OSP.Shop_DTO+RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'url', line 1, position 7."

**My JSON looks like this:**

```
{
    "url": "http://www.myurl.com/-shop-item.html",
    "result": {
        "extractorData": {
            "url": "http://www.myurl.com/-shop-item.html",
            "resourceId": "1db49f66afc2f234cb5ab470f0c39e0c",
                "data": [
                {
                    "group": [
                        {
                            "BN_shop_1KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$36.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_2KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$69"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_3KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$97"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_VEGE_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "3 KG = $97"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_4KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$124"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$149"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "pageData": {
            "resourceId": "1db49f66afc2f234cb5ab470f0c39e0c",
            "statusCode": 200,
            "timestamp": 1476432605275
        },
        "timestamp": 1476432606594,
        "sequenceNumber": 0
    }
}{
    "url": "http://www.myurl.com/-shop-concentrate.html",
    "result": {
        "extractorData": {
            "url": "http://www.myurl.com/-shop-concentrate.html",
            "resourceId": "dd4837cc7d0085eae005243c7bd8ca8a",
            "data": [
                {
                    "group": [
                        {
                            "BN_shop_1KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$27.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_2KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$49"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_3KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$69"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_VEGE_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "3 KG = $69"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_4KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$84"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$99"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "pageData": {
            "resourceId": "dd4837cc7d0085eae005243c7bd8ca8a",
            "statusCode": 200,
            "timestamp": 1476432604237
        },
        "timestamp": 1476432605124,
        "sequenceNumber": 1
    }
}{
    "url": "http://www.myurl.comshop-matrix.html",
    "result": {
        "extractorData": {
            "url": "http://www.myurl.comshop-matrix.html",
            "resourceId": "deee30ffa0098e017a06c0e0c805e133",
            "data": [
                {
                    "group": [
                        {
                            "BN_shop_1KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$29.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_2KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$56"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_3KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$79"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_VEGE_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "3 KG = $79"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_4KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$99"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$119"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "pageData": {
            "resourceId": "deee30ffa0098e017a06c0e0c805e133",
            "statusCode": 200,
            "timestamp": 1476432602408
        },
        "timestamp": 1476432603204,
        "sequenceNumber": 2
    }
}{
    "url": "http://www.myurl.comsoy-shop-item.html",
    "result": {
        "extractorData": {
            "url": "http://www.myurl.comsoy-shop-item.html",
            "resourceId": "5593aad40f95ba868626e47a1b550813",
            "data": [
                {
                    "group": [
                        {
                            "BN_shop_1KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$25.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_2KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$45"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_3KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$89"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_VEGE_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "5 KG = $89"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_4KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$175"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$339"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "pageData": {
            "resourceId": "5593aad40f95ba868626e47a1b550813",
            "statusCode": 200,
            "timestamp": 1476432602479
        },
        "timestamp": 1476432603847,
        "sequenceNumber": 3
    }
}{
    "url": "http://www.myurl.compea-shop.html",
    "result": {
        "extractorData": {
            "url": "http://www.myurl.compea-shop.html",
            "resourceId": "f91e05d0265ab5a5f7f948c57a05bced",
            "data": [
                {
                    "group": [
                        {
                            "BN_shop_1KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$25.00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_2KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$45"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_3KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$89"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_VEGE_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "5 KG = $89"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_4KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$169"
                                }
                            ],
                            "BN_shop_5KG": [
                                {
                                    "text": "$319"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "pageData": {
            "resourceId": "f91e05d0265ab5a5f7f948c57a05bced",
            "statusCode": 200,
            "timestamp": 1476432605227
        },
        "timestamp": 1476432606451,
        "sequenceNumber": 4
    }
}
```

**Model looks like this:**

```
public class BNShop1KG
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class BNShop2KG
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class BNShop3KG
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class BNVEGE5KG
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class BNShop4KG
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class BNShop5KG
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public List<BNShop1KG> BN_shop_1KG { get; set; }
    public List<BNShop2KG> BN_shop_2KG { get; set; }
    public List<BNShop3KG> BN_shop_3KG { get; set; }
    public List<BNVEGE5KG> BN_VEGE_5KG { get; set; }
    public List<BNShop4KG> BN_shop_4KG { get; set; }
    public List<BNShop5KG> BN_shop_5KG { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public List<Group> group { get; set; }
}

public class ExtractorData
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string resourceId { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class PageData
{
    public string resourceId { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public ExtractorData extractorData { get; set; }
    public PageData pageData { get; set; }
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
    public int sequenceNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

In my code i'm trying to get access to the 'text' value in 'BN_shop_1KG' from the first JSON object. This item:

```
"BN_shop_1KG": [
   {
        "text": "$36.00"
   }
```

**I've tried the following in my code, but am receiving the error outlined above. From what I understand reading some previous threads about this is that I will need to use a deserialize into List to handle JSON received in this manner:**

```
    List<Shop_DTO.RootObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shop_DTO.RootObject>>(_rawHtmlResult);

    var price = obj.First().result.extractorData.data[0].group[0].BN_shop_1kg[0].text;
    Debug.WriteLine("Price for item {0}", price);
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated, i've been stuck on this for a couple of days :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Json file is invalid. Since it contains multiple Json object, it should be a Json array which needs to be wrapped by [], and another thing is between each Json object, you need ","

```
var jsonText = @"[{
""url"": ""http://www.myurl.com/-shop-item.html"",
""result"": {
    ""extractorData"": {
        ""url"": ""http://www.myurl.com/-shop-item.html"",
        ""resourceId"": ""1db49f66afc2f234cb5ab470f0c39e0c"",
            ""data"": [
            {
                ""group"": [
                    {
                        ""BN_shop_1KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$36.00""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_2KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$69""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_3KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$97""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_VEGE_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""3 KG = $97""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_4KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$124""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$149""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ""pageData"": {
        ""resourceId"": ""1db49f66afc2f234cb5ab470f0c39e0c"",
        ""statusCode"": 200,
        ""timestamp"": 1476432605275
    },
    ""timestamp"": 1476432606594,
    ""sequenceNumber"": 0
}
},{
""url"": ""http://www.myurl.com/-shop-concentrate.html"",
""result"": {
    ""extractorData"": {
        ""url"": ""http://www.myurl.com/-shop-concentrate.html"",
        ""resourceId"": ""dd4837cc7d0085eae005243c7bd8ca8a"",
        ""data"": [
            {
                ""group"": [
                    {
                        ""BN_shop_1KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$27.00""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_2KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$49""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_3KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$69""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_VEGE_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""3 KG = $69""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_4KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$84""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$99""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ""pageData"": {
        ""resourceId"": ""dd4837cc7d0085eae005243c7bd8ca8a"",
        ""statusCode"": 200,
        ""timestamp"": 1476432604237
    },
    ""timestamp"": 1476432605124,
    ""sequenceNumber"": 1
}
},{
""url"": ""http://www.myurl.comshop-matrix.html"",
""result"": {
    ""extractorData"": {
        ""url"": ""http://www.myurl.comshop-matrix.html"",
        ""resourceId"": ""deee30ffa0098e017a06c0e0c805e133"",
        ""data"": [
            {
                ""group"": [
                    {
                        ""BN_shop_1KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$29.00""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_2KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$56""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_3KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$79""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_VEGE_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""3 KG = $79""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_4KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$99""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$119""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ""pageData"": {
        ""resourceId"": ""deee30ffa0098e017a06c0e0c805e133"",
        ""statusCode"": 200,
        ""timestamp"": 1476432602408
    },
    ""timestamp"": 1476432603204,
    ""sequenceNumber"": 2
}
},{
""url"": ""http://www.myurl.comsoy-shop-item.html"",
""result"": {
    ""extractorData"": {
        ""url"": ""http://www.myurl.comsoy-shop-item.html"",
        ""resourceId"": ""5593aad40f95ba868626e47a1b550813"",
        ""data"": [
            {
                ""group"": [
                    {
                        ""BN_shop_1KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$25.00""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_2KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$45""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_3KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$89""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_VEGE_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""5 KG = $89""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_4KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$175""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$339""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ""pageData"": {
        ""resourceId"": ""5593aad40f95ba868626e47a1b550813"",
        ""statusCode"": 200,
        ""timestamp"": 1476432602479
    },
    ""timestamp"": 1476432603847,
    ""sequenceNumber"": 3
}
},{
""url"": ""http://www.myurl.compea-shop.html"",
""result"": {
    ""extractorData"": {
        ""url"": ""http://www.myurl.compea-shop.html"",
        ""resourceId"": ""f91e05d0265ab5a5f7f948c57a05bced"",
        ""data"": [
            {
                ""group"": [
                    {
                        ""BN_shop_1KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$25.00""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_2KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$45""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_3KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$89""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_VEGE_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""5 KG = $89""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_4KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$169""
                            }
                        ],
                        ""BN_shop_5KG"": [
                            {
                                ""text"": ""$319""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ""pageData"": {
        ""resourceId"": ""f91e05d0265ab5a5f7f948c57a05bced"",
        ""statusCode"": 200,
        ""timestamp"": 1476432605227
    },
    ""timestamp"": 1476432606451,
    ""sequenceNumber"": 4
}
}]"
```

Then you can use your code to get the price. Btw, there is a typo in your code, `BN_shop_1kg` is supposed to be `BN_shop_1KG`

Comment: Great thanks, so i've tried that and it works, however as the json is being returned via a REST API how am I going to be able to insert the "," between the objects? I can modify the JSON easily enough to append the array [] characters, but unsure how to reliably insert the ",". Ive got the below code to append the [], can I build off this?

Comment: Sorry code is here: 
var jsonText = @"[" + _rawHtmlResult + "]";

Comment: jsonText.Replace("}{", "},{");

Comment: awesome, thanks for the help. Appreciate your time :)

Comment: Just as a follow up, I thought it would be interesting to pass on that I needed to use the following line to replace all lines breaks in the JSON before the jsonText.Replace("}{", "},{"); line would work. Took me a few hours of debugging. Here is the line i used;

jsonText = Regex.Replace(jsonText, @"\r\n?|\n", "");