# Deserializing a JSON object with multiple columns including datetime properties

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

In a C# project, I'm retrieving an Event object, with subject (string), location (string), start_time (datetime), end_time (datetime), all_day_event (boolean) and calendar_id (int) properties, as a JSON response from a Rest request. That request gets data from a database and start_time and end_time columns' types are datetime on that database too. But I'm having trouble about getting the datetime type values. I get the JSON object like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "subject": "Test Event 1",
    "location": "Test Location",
    "start_time": "2019-08-22 10:17:53",
    "end_time": "2019-08-22 10:17:55",
    "all_day_event": 0,
    "calendar_id": 1
  }
]
```

This is my Event class:

```
public class Event {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        public bool AllDayEvent { get; set; }

        public int CalendarId { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is how I deserialize the JSON object:

```
events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event[]>(response.Content);
```

When I print that JSON object directly, it is displayed correctly. But after I deserialize it, the time values are displayed as 01/01/0001 12:00 AM. I've searched for a while. I've found [Deserialize Json Object - DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043412/deserialize-json-object-datetime), [Deserializing Import Io JSON with multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065379/deserializing-import-io-json-with-multiple-objects), [Deserialize multiple json into object c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585029/deserialize-multiple-json-into-object-c-sharp) suggestions but they didn't help. So is there any way to get those time values properly?? Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to apply `[JsonProperty("start_time")]` attribute to `StartTime` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aleks said, you need to decorate properties which have different naming convention. Keep in mind, Json.Net will automatically map JSON's *snakeCase* into C#'s *PascalCase* properties. However, if you have *snake_case* or something else, you need to decorate properties.

```
public class Event 
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("start_time")]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("end_time")]
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("all_day_event")]
        public bool AllDayEvent { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("calendar_id")]
        public int CalendarId { get; set; }
    }
```

In addition, you can set global naming strategy, to avoid decorating all the properties of your model, if JSON follows snake_case for [example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm)

Comment: @OğuzÖztınaz check documentation example, maybe it will be better for you to use SnakeCaseNamingStrategy instead of decorating all the models you (might) have